# Does intersection equal product for infinitely many comaximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

If $I_1,...,I_n$ are comaximal ideals in a commutative ring, then $I_1\cdots I_n=I_1\cap \cdots \cap I_n$. Does this extend to infinitely many comaximal ideals? The proof I have seen uses induction, so not sure if this does extend.

Comment: How do you define an infinite product of ideals?

Answer (score 2):

Posting a CW Answer per @DylanMoreland's Comment:

The intersection of an arbitrary family of ideals makes sense, but the *product* of an infinite number of pairwise coprime ideals (even if the ring is commutative with unity) stands in need of definition.  Of course one might choose to *define* the product in this case to agree with the intersection, but that kind of short-circuit is best avoided (unless it happens to serve an author's purpose).